# How to set PYODBC to return Decimal datatypes and prevent scientific notation (without needing to convert to other datatypes)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyodbc, scientific-notation

I'm using PYODBC to pull data from a SQL Server database. The underlying datatype is `decimal(24, 12)`. The value, 0.000000000000, is being returned as python `decimal.Decimal('0E-12')`.

The data is being written to a csv file and of course is being written as 0E-12 instead of 0.000000000000 or just 0.

I'm looking for a PYODBC setting that will prevent the 0.000000000000 from returning as decimal.Decimal(0E-12) and haven't found anything.

The way I am currently doing things is to convert the values to a string and then specify the formatting. I've done this both in T-SQL (which performs better) and in python (which is simpler IMO because by returning a decimal type instead of string, the csv module handles quoting better) but neither seem to be the "right" way.

In Python:

```
import pyodbc
import decimal

cn = ...
cr = cn.cursor()
cr.execute("SELECT MyColumn, ... FROM MyView")
data = cr.fetchall()

with open(csv_path, mode='w', newline='') as csv_f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    csv_writer.writerow(cols)
    for r in data:
        for (i, c) in enumerate(cr.description):
            if c[1] == decimal.Decimal:
                d, scale = r[i], c[5]
                r[i] = f"{d:{scale}f}"

    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

In T-SQL:

```
import pyodbc

cn = ...
cr = cn.cursor()
cr.execute("SELECT convert(varchar(24), MyColumn) as MyColumn, ... FROM MyView")
data = cr.fetchall()
```

While these do work (and is the same advice I get searching online so far), I'm thinking any conversion shouldn't be needed since the underlying datatype in sql and python are correct. A decimal(24, 12) should return as a python decimal.Decimal and that is what is happening but the value 0.000000000000 shouldn't be converted to decimal.Decimal('0E-12'). Scientific notation here is unnecessary.

If I just create a variable `myvar=decimal.Decimal(0.000000000000)` Python returns `decimal.Decimal('0')` (which is what I want). This is why I figure pyodbc is doing something to tell it to return in scientific notation and **TLDR** I'd like to find a way to tell it not to do that, so the process doesn't have to spend resources on unnecessary conversions.

Comment: Not sure if this will or will not make sense for your use case, but can you adjust your write-to-csv process by adding something like a `float_format` argument?

Comment: "I'm looking for a PYODBC setting that will prevent the 0.000000000000 from returning as decimal.Decimal(0E-12)" - There isn't one. As the above comment suggests, you'll need to specify the formatting when you send the value to the CSV file. Something like `f"{my_decimal_value:0.12f}"` might suffice.

Comment: @GordThomson that was what I expected but figured I'd try. Since my datasets are less than 10M rows and converting to a string then back to decimal isn't eating a lot of resources I'll just keep converting the values on the way into the csv.

Comment: @Isolated, GordThompson Thanks for the direction, that helped. I tried a few different things based on that feedback. float_format seems to be a pandas csv thing and isn't part of the csv module in python and since Gord confirms that pyodbc doesn't control this I've settled on converting to a string in the T-SQL since even when using the python string format, any conversion back to decimal.Decimal seems to be returning scientific notation. Thanks again.